# Insert file (foo.txt) into open file (bar.txt) at caret position

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

What would be the best method, please, to insert file (foo.txt) into open file (bar.txt) at caret position?

It would be nice to have an open-file dialog to choose anything to be inserted.

The word processing equivalent would be "insert file" here.

Here is a substitute for `foo.sublime-snippet`, which can be linked to form files elsewhere:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin    

class InsertFileCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):    

        v = self.view    

        template = open('foo.txt').read()    

        print template    

        v.run_command("insert_snippet", {"contents": template})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my unofficial modification of https://github.com/mneuhaus/SublimeFileTemplates which permits me to `insert-a-file-here` using the quick panel.  It works on an OSX operating system (running Mountain Lion).

The only disadvantage I see so far is the inability to translate a double-slash `\\` in the form file correctly -- it gets inserted instead as just a single-slash `\`.  In my LaTex form files, the double-slash `\\` represents a line ending, or a new line if preceded by a `~`.  The workaround is to insert an extra slash at each occurrence in the actual form file (i.e., put three slashes, with the understanding that only two slashes will be inserted when running the plugin).  The form files need to be LF endings and I'm using UTF-8 encoding -- CR endings are not translated properly.  With a slight modification, it is also possible to have multiple form file directories and/or file types.

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin
import os    

class InsertFileCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):    

    def run(self):
        self.find_templates()
        self.window.show_quick_panel(self.templates, self.template_selected)

    def find_templates(self):
        self.templates = []
        self.template_paths = []    

        for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('/path_to_forms_directory'):
            for filename in filenames:
                if filename.endswith(".tex"): # extension of form files
                    self.template_paths.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
                    self.templates.append(os.path.basename(root) + ": " + os.path.splitext(filename)[0])    

    def template_selected(self, selected_index):
        if selected_index != -1:
            self.template_path = self.template_paths[selected_index]    

            print "\n" * 25
            print "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n"
            print ("Inserting File:  " + self.template_path + "\n")
            print "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n"    

            template = open(self.template_path).read()    

            print template    

            view = self.window.run_command("insert_snippet", {'contents': template})    

            sublime.status_message("Inserted File: %s" % self.template_path)
```

Answer (score 1):

From within a text command you can access the current view. You can get the cursor positions using `self.view.sel()`. I don't know how to do gui stuff in python, but you can do file selection using the quick panel (similar to [FuzzyFileNav](https://github.com/facelessuser/FuzzyFileNav)).

Comment: Thank you for the tip -- it looks like this plugin is going to be a modification of "Hello, World!" insert at cursor.  I'll keep working on it.

Comment: I think I am on the right track, and I have updated my question with a simple working example (without an open file dialog).  It looks like the easiest solution may be to modify https://github.com/mneuhaus/SublimeFileTemplates so that templates with include file references are inserted into the open file tab (without a project required), instead of creating a new file that requires an open project.  I installed FuzzyFileNav and am still thinking about how that might be incorporated.  HelloWorld-here from your lesson on day one may not be suited for this particular issue of `insert file here`.

Comment: Sounds good. Glad to hear you are making progress. Keep in mind that using the command `insert_snippet` will insert the contents at all of the cursors. Of course, it may not matter for you, so just a general note.